# Unsupported projection option $in in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I tried to use something like this in pymongo:

```
list(db[collectionName].find({}, {fieldName: {"$in": [value1, value2]}}))
```

but I get an error that its unsupported projection option. How can I correct it?

Comment: Are you trying to get document where the `fieldName`'s value is either of those values ?

Comment: Yes thats my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to match documents, the conditions go in query predicate and not in projection. So try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
list(db[collectionName].find({ fieldName: {"$in": [value1, value2]} }))
```

Comment: There is still a problem. It doesn't work when I want to set the condition for field `Field1.Field2`.

Comment: So this: `list(db[collectionName].find({ fieldName1.fieldName2: {"$in": [value1, value2]} }))
` doesnt work :(

Comment: @Degel what issue do you get now? For querying on nested fields you'll have to wrap them in quotes `.find({ "fieldName1.fieldName2": ...`

Comment: I created new topic for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369579/pymongo-find-query-problem-projection-works